# Why does Cady say "I ain't your porch-baby"

Tags: analysis, dialogue, cape-fear-1991

In Martin Scorsese's movie *Cape Fear (1991)* Cady has a brief exchange with a PI hired by Sam Bowden

> Cady: Are you my friend?
>
> PI: No, I'm not your friend.
>
> Cady: Oh. 'Cause I thought maybe you were my friend, because I like to plan my comings and goings with friends. But if you're not my friend, and you're planning my comings and goings, I'd call that presumptuous. In fact, I'd call it downright rude, because **I ain't your porch-baby**, buddy.

The first half of Cady's line is pretty easy to understand. What does he say "I ain't your porch-baby"? I am not sure if he is being menacing with that line.

Comment: No real hits when googled. Closest is "Porch Monkey" which is in Urban Dictionary -- a jobless person who sits on the porch all day watching the world go by. Maybe two people who do this together would be considered close friends? And "monkey" was considered potentially racist?